# Can I see the actual collation (of e. g. Latin1) as used in for instance MySQL or Windows? The order of characters, not the name

Tags: windows, mysql, sql-server

I searched, and all I find is descriptions of the names, and the selection of collations.

For example:

```
_Zulu
0Alpha
Alpha
alpha
```

usually sorts this way (on US Windows, most SQL servers etc.), underscore first. This is done, of course, according to the configured collation. This collation has a name, but that's not what I want to know.

What I want to know, is: what IS the collation? How is it actually made up?

Something like:

```
_
0
1
2
3
4
...
a
...
A
...
Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collations (at least for Unicode) [are based](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) on the following specificatons:

http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/30/collation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of letters in various MySQL `COLLATIONs` is given [*here*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) for `utf8` and [*here*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) for `utf8mb4`.